# Get Touch Event Relative To Under-Sized Frame Buffer Object

Tags: javascript, three.js

I coded a fluid simulation using shaders (I used THREE.js) for my webpage. I wanted it to run fast even on mobile, so I decided that I was going to simulate on a lower resolution (4 times smaller than the Render Target), I managed to get it working for Mouse Events, but I haven't been able to decipher how to properly scale Touch Events so that they matche real touch positions.

```
function handleMove(evt) {

        evt.preventDefault();
        var touches = evt.targetTouches;
        var x = 0, y = 0;

        if (BufferBUniforms.iMouse.value.z === 1) {

            var element = document.getElementById("container").getBoundingClientRect();
            var bodyRect = document.body.getBoundingClientRect();

            var h = (element.top - bodyRect.top);
            var w = (element.left - bodyRect.left);

            // One way I tried.
            x = ( touches[0].pageX - w ) / scaleMax;
            y = height - ( touches[0].pageY - h ) / scaleMax;

            // Another way I tried.
            x = ( touches[0].pageX - w ) / scaleMax;
            y = height - ( touches[0].pageY - h ) / scaleMaxO;

            BufferAUniforms.iMouse.value.x = x;
            BufferAUniforms.iMouse.value.y = y;

        }

    }
```

This is a snippet where I defined some of the variables mentioned above:

```
scale = window.devicePixelRatio;
renderer.setPixelRatio(scale);
container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

height = window.innerHeight * 0.25;
height = THREE.Math.floorPowerOfTwo( height )
scaleMax = window.innerHeight / height;
width = window.innerWidth * 0.25;
width = THREE.Math.floorPowerOfTwo(width)
scaleRatio = width / height;
scaleMaxO = window.innerWidth / width;
renderer.setSize(width * scaleMax, height * scaleMaxO);
```

The thing is that it works when using Chrome Dev Tools on Mobile Emulator, but not when using a Samsung S9 Plus.

[You can see the whole thing here](https://felipunky.github.io/html/fluidsMobile.html)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're drawing that smaller render target to fill the canvas it should just be

```
const rect = renderer.domElement.getBoundingClientRect();
const x = (touches[0].clientX - rect.left) * renderTargetWidth / rect.width;
const y = (touches[0].clientY - rect.top ) * renderTargetHeight / rect.height;
```

Now X and Y are in pixels in the render target though you might want to flip Y

```
const y = renderTargetHeight - 
     (touches[0].clientY - rect.top) * renderTargetHeight / rect.height;
```

Note the mouse is no different. In fact this should work

```
function computeRenderTargetRelativePosition(e) {
  const rect = renderer.domElement.getBoundingClientRect();
  const x = (e.clientX - rect.left) * renderTargetWidth  / rect.width;
  const y = (e.clientY - rect.top ) * renderTargetHeight / rect.height;
  return {x, y};
}

renderer.domElement.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
  const pos = computeRenderTargetRelativePosition(e);
  ... do something with pos...
});

renderer.domElement.addEventListener('touchmove', (e) => {
  const pos = computeRenderTargetRelativePosition(e.touches[0]);
  ... do something with pos...
});
```

The only complication is if you apply CSS transforms then you need different code.

```js
'use strict';

/* global THREE */

function main() {
  const canvas = document.querySelector('#c');
  const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas});

  const rtWidth = 24;
  const rtHeight = 12;
  const renderTarget = new THREE.WebGLRenderTarget(rtWidth, rtHeight);

  const rtCamera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera(0, rtWidth, rtHeight, 0, -1, 1);
  const rtScene = new THREE.Scene();

  const boxWidth = 1;
  const boxHeight = 1;
  const boxDepth = 1;
  const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(boxWidth, boxHeight, boxDepth);

  const rtMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 'red'});
  const rtCube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, rtMaterial);
  rtScene.add(rtCube);

  const camera = new THREE.Camera();
  const scene = new THREE.Scene();

  const planeGeo = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(2, 2);
  const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
    //color: 'blue',
    map: renderTarget.texture,
  });
  const plane = new THREE.Mesh(planeGeo, material);
  scene.add(plane);

  function resizeRendererToDisplaySize(renderer) {
    const canvas = renderer.domElement;
    const width = canvas.clientWidth;
    const height = canvas.clientHeight;
    const needResize = canvas.width !== width || canvas.height !== height;
    if (needResize) {
      renderer.setSize(width, height, false);
    }
    return needResize;
  }

  function render(time) {
    time *= 0.001;

    if (resizeRendererToDisplaySize(renderer)) {
      const canvas = renderer.domElement;
    }

    // draw render target scene to render target
    renderer.setRenderTarget(renderTarget);
    renderer.render(rtScene, rtCamera);
    renderer.setRenderTarget(null);

    // render the scene to the canvas
    renderer.render(scene, camera);

    requestAnimationFrame(render);
  }

  requestAnimationFrame(render);
  
  function setPos(e) {
    const rect = renderer.domElement.getBoundingClientRect();
    const x =            (e.clientX - rect.left) * rtWidth  / rect.width;
    const y = rtHeight - (e.clientY - rect.top ) * rtHeight / rect.height;

    rtCube.position.set(x, y, 0);
  }  

  renderer.domElement.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
    setPos(e);
  });

  renderer.domElement.addEventListener('touchmove', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    setPos(e.touches[0]);

  }, {passive: false});
}

main();
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
#c {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
<script src="https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/threejs/r105/three.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Yep Ive got transforms and I also need to map the coordinates to the scaling Im applying, so divide by the scale ratio of the real window with respect to the scaled down one, I am just getting crazy by how my code works in the Dev Tools Emulator but not in a real phone.

Comment: `y = height * ( scaleMaxO / scaleMax ) - ( touches[0].pageY - h ) / scaleMax;`
Works on my MacBook with the emulator from Chrome, but on my phone it doesn't!

Comment: you have **CSS** transforms???? That not normal. 99.999% of three.js apps do not use CSS transforms so you shouldn't need more complicated code

Comment: stop using pageY. use clientY. stop referencing the body. it's irrelevant

Comment: Let me try with no CSS transforms and client instead of page.

Comment: No transforms, this works on the emulator: 
`const rect = renderer.domElement.getBoundingClientRect();
                const x = touches[0].clientX * width / rect.width;
                const y = height - ( touches[0].clientY * height / rect.height );`
This one also works on the emulator:
`x = ( touches[0].clientX ) / scaleMaxO;
                y = height - ( touches[0].clientY ) / scaleMax;`
But none of them work on my phone.
I wonder if it has to do with the pixel ratio.

Comment: Thanks for the update! But it still doesn't work I think it has to do with the pixel ratio. But it is very hard to debug as it has different behavior in the emulator than on the real thing, I am going to do remote debugging to see if I can fix it.

Comment: Although I added a link, the question has the code where the problem is. I don't get why the down vote. When I get the time I will try to create a snippet that encompasses only the problem stated in the question.